# How to color a column in mui table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I’m having trouble coloring columns in a mui table.

How do I color a column?  Lets say green.  From the data below, I want to color the name column.
im assuming i have to check while im iterating whether the column name == 'name' and i have to do something which i'm not sure of.  thanks

My data:

```
data = [{name: “jack”, age: 22},
        {name: “Robert”, age: 33}]
headers = [“name”, “age”]

<TableContainer>
component={Paper}
sx={{
    flex: 1
    flexBasis: 0,
    flexDirection: 'column'
    }}>
<Table stickHeader aria-label="test table" size="small">
    <TableHead>
       <TableRow aria-label="test table">
         {headers.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <TableCell sx={{pl:1, pr:1}} key={idx}>
              {item}
            <TableCell>
            );
           })};
         </TableRow>
      <TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {data.map((record, rowid) => {
           return (
             <TableRow
               key={rowid}
               sx={{'&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border: 0}}}>
               {headers.map((item, tableidx) => (
                 <TableCell
                  size="small"
                  sx={{...{pr: 1, pl:1},}}
                  key={tableidx}>
                  {record[item]}
                 </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              );})}
              </TableBody>
     </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

AFter getting help, i have this now:

```
     what i have now is like this: 

{index?.map((idx) => initialTable[idx]).map((row, rowid) => {
return (
<TableRow
   style={
       rowid % 2 ? 
            {
                background: theme.palette.action.hover,
             }
          :{}
}
key={rowid}
sx={{'&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border: 0}}}>
{(columns.map(
  (item, tableidx) => (
       <TableCell
            size="small"
            sx={{
                ...{
                    pr: 1,
                    pl: 1,
                   ...(item === 'ticker' && {backgroundColor: 'yellow'}),
                   ...(item==='volatility' && {
                       backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 185, 0.4)',
                      }),
```

what i am having trouble is using useTheme to use the same rgba color code.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done in various ways, but the most simple way is the following:

You could change any cell color by adding conditional JSON or index/specific name, etc.

For example:

```
...item === 'name' && {color: 'green'}
```

Or like this `color: tableidx === 0 ? 'green' : 'inherit'`, `item === 'name' ? 'green' : 'inherit'`

```
        ...
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((record, rowid) => {
            return (
              <TableRow
                key={rowid}
                sx={{'&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border: 0}}}
              >
                {headers.map((item, tableidx) => (
                  <TableCell
                    size="small"
                    sx={{
                      pr: 1,
                      pl:1,
                      ...item === 'name' && {color: 'green'}
                    }}
                    key={tableidx}
                  >
                    {record[item]}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            )})}
        </TableBody>
       ...
```

[image]

Comment: im curious, is there anyway of using usetheme() from mui to map colors instead of hardcoding some of the colors?

Comment: @turtle_in_mind Yes, you can do. It could be done in various ways. First one is using the predefined colors like `color: green[500]` or from your custom theme like `color: theme.palette.secondary.main`, etc. You could check this codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/using-various-colors-in-mui-4qgzt8?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: If you want to discuss further, please tick this as a correct answer then we could move to a next discussion. Thanks!

Comment: how do I get in touch with you?

Comment: i have edited the code above to include my current solution but i was told not to hardcode those values and to use useTheme() instead through my code review.  thanks